# Problems getting AJAX working in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am pretty sure that this is something really basic I am missing, but it's driving me nuts. Please help me out :-)

I am trying to get a basic AJAX call to work from within my own wordpress plugin.

I have two files:

**bha-class.php**

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'my_action_javascript' );

function my_action_javascript() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var data = {
        'action': 'my_action',
        'whatever': 1234
    };

    // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
});
</script>
<?
}
?>
```

and **bha-class-xhr.php**

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );

function my_action_callback() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );

    $whatever += 10;

        echo $whatever;

    die(); // this is required to return a proper result
}

?>
```

Things are working and the AJAX call is launched and `bha-class-xhr.php called.

However I get the error:

```
Got this from the server: <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function add_action() in <b>/var/www/institutforgestaltanalyse.dk/public_html/wp-content/plugins/bha-member-system/include/bha-class-xhr.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
```

So it seems the xhr file I am calling is not recognized within the Wordpress framework.

What did I miss?

Comment: where are you including `bha-class-xhr.php?` it seems strange that you would get that error as `add_action` should be defined by word-press, try including it in your `functions.php`

Comment: I found this article more useful than the WordPress page you mentioned: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/30/how-to-create-a-wordpress-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling your `bha-class-xhr.php` file directly from javascript. That is not the right file to call if you need WordPress.

Instead you should make your ajax call to the `admin-ajax.php` adding an action and other parameters if necessary.

Something like (depending on your installation and I am using GET here instead of POST):

```
/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_action_callback
```

Comment: Well you are right! And I shouldn't. Somehow I am missing somethings central. I am trying to get this example to work, but simply can't :-)
http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: I got it working. If I the code in the `bha-class-xhr.php` in my main plugin file it works. Why? How can I place my callback functions in another file than the mail plugin file?

Comment: @ThomasK.Nielsen Check the link I added below your question.